# position and velocity data using accelerometer and gyroscope in iphone

Tags: swift, position, accelerometer, gyroscope, integral

I am trying to estimate the distance travelled by iPhone using the accelerometer and gyro. I learned from other related posts that it would cause a huge error due to the constants but still I need to learn how to do this double integral operation on swift.

Could someone help me how to calculate the velocity from acceleration on swift?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post what you have tried and what you have achieved still now and also you need to post what error or where you are unable to move ahead ?

Comment: have you been successful in the meantime?